# The form of this 2nd order ODE is like nothing I've been taught how to solve, any pointers?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm looking to find the Boundary Value Problem for this inhomogeneous differential equation:

- $(x+1)y''+y'=-1$

with conditions $y(0) = 0$ and $y'(1) = 0$.

I've been hinted towards writing this ODE in the form $\frac {d}{dx}$$(r(x)\frac {dy}{dx})$ where I have calculated $r(x)$ as $x+1$ but I'm not sure where to go from here.

I know how to solve 2nd order inhomogeneous ODEs if the coefficients were constants (via the educated guess method) or if it was in Euler form (use $x = e^t$) but I'd like to know how to solve 2nd order ODEs like this one. Thanks

Edit: Changed typo y to y'

Comment: The expression you wrote for the form of the ODE is not an equation (since it lacks an = sign), and I don’t see how it could have a similar form since there are no first derivatives $y’$. Are you sure the equation is correct?

Comment: Are you looking to transform the ODE into a normal form for BVP, like $(pz')'+qz=f$? Or are you looking for a variational formulation as step towards a Ritz discretization?

Comment: Should that $y$ be a $y'$? Then the left hand side will have the form you said.

Comment: @Paul Yes sorry you're right, but even with the form I was hinted at working towards, I don't understand how to form the solution.

Comment: @Bcpicao Very sorry, changed y to y'.

Comment: @LutzLehmann I haven't heard of a Ritz discretization yet, so probably not. Usually to solve BVPs, I find the solution with 2 missing constats c1 and c2 and then plug in the conditions to find them

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez My issue is I don't know how to deal with a coefficient other than a constant or $ax^2y'' + bxy' + cy$

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Yea you're right, it's just that I usually get tripped up on examples I haven't encountered before. Now that I know how to solve these types of ODEs, I can do them much easier in the future

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The hint you mentioned is a good one:
$$
(x+1)y''+y'=[(x+1)y']'=-1 \implies (x+1)y'=-x+C_1. \tag{1}
$$
The condition $y'(1)=0$ implies $C_1=1$, hence
$$
y'=\frac{1-x}{1+x}=\frac{2}{1+x}-1 \implies y=2\ln|1+x|-x+C_2. \tag{2}
$$
The condition $y(0)=0$ implies $C_2=0$, therefore
$$
y=2\ln|1+x|-x. \tag{3}
$$

Comment: This is perfect, thank you

Answer (score 1):

As was mentioned in the comments, by observation we see a "perfect" derivative (like a perfect square): $$\frac{d}{dx}\left[(x+1)y'\right] = -1.$$ Integrate both sides w.r.t. $x$: $$\int\frac{d}{dx}\left[(x+1)y'\right] dx = \int -1 dx$$

$$\implies (x+1)y'= -x+C$$ $$\implies y' = \frac{-x+C}{x+1}.$$ Inserting the second initial condition we have $y'(1)=0=\frac{-1+C}{2}.$ This means $C=1$. Now integrate once again:$$\int\frac{dy}{dx} dx = \int \frac{1-x}{1+x} dx = \int \frac{1}{1+x}-\frac{x}{1+x}dx.$$

Thus, (using the ol' add n' subtract +1-1) $$y(x)=\int \frac{1}{1+x}-\left(-\frac{1}{1+x} +1\right)dx.$$

$$\implies y(x)=2\ln|x+1|-x+K.$$ Put in the first I.C. to obtain $y(0)=0=K.$

So, the solution to this ODE is $$y(x)=2\ln|x+1|-x.$$ You should re-input this function back in the ODE to check. If the function is flowing forward in time then we don't need the $|\cdot|$.

Comment: Or you could write $y(x)=\ln(x+1)^2 -x.$

Comment: My solution via the Laplace transform method gives exactly the same result as your approach. Please take a look!

Answer (score 0):

$(x+1)y''+y'=-1$; Eq.(1)

Take Laplace transform of the both sides of Eq. (1). It yields that

$-\cfrac{d}{ds}\left[s^2Y(s)-sy(0)-y'(0) \right]+s^2Y(s)-sy(0)-y'(0)+sY(s)-y(0)=-\cfrac{1}{s}$; Eq.(2)

Let us take $y'(0)=a$ and move forward. Eq.(2) is reduced to

$\cfrac{dY}{ds}+\left(\cfrac{1}{s}-1\right)Y=-\cfrac{a}{s^2}+\cfrac{1}{s^3}$; Eq.(3)

Obviously, Eq.(3) is a first-order linear ODE that has the following exact solution:

$Y=\cfrac{1}{s\hspace{0.1cm}e^{-s}}\left[ \int \left(-\cfrac{a}{s^2}+\cfrac{1}{s^3} \right)s\hspace{0.1cm}e^{-s}ds+C\right]$; Eq. (4)

It follows that

$Y=\cfrac{e^s}{s}\left[ -(a+1)Ei(-s) -\cfrac{e^{-s}}{s}+C\right]$; Eq. (5)

where $Ei$ denotes exponential integral. Eq.(5) simplifies to

$Y=C\cfrac{e^s}{s}-\cfrac{1}{s^2}-\cfrac{(a+1) e^sEi(-s)}{s}$; Eq.(6)

It follows from Eq.(6) that

$y=C\mathscr{L}^{-1} \left\{\cfrac{e^s}{s}\right\} -x -(a+1)\mathscr{L}^{-1} \left\{\cfrac{e^sEi(-s)}{s}\right\}$; Eq.(7)

which reduces to

$y=C\mathscr{L}^{-1} \left\{\cfrac{e^s}{s}\right\} -x +(a+1)\ln \mid x+1 \mid$; Eq.(8)

Using the IBC $y(0)=0$ in Eq.(8), we deduce $C=0$. So,

$y=-x +(a+1)\ln \mid x+1 \mid$; Eq.(9)

Obviously,

$y'=-1 +\cfrac{a+1}{x+1}$; Eq.(10)

Since $y'(1)=0$, we conclude $a=1$.

Finally, $y=-x+2\ln \mid x+1\mid$.